How to solve this comparative static?
I want to study how $n$ varies with $m$. They have the following relations:
$$n^{-\frac{\sigma}{\alpha(\sigma-1)}}\left(\frac{\frac{f(\sigma-1)}{m}}{L-\frac{n\sigma f}{m}}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}=n^{\frac{1}{1-\sigma}}\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}$$
For more context, $n$ is the number of varieties and $m$ is the size of the economy. $\sigma,\alpha$ are elasticities. $f$ is the fixed cost. $L$ is the labor supplied.
How do I calculate $\frac{\partial n}{\partial m}$?

Looks ugly. Have you tried implicit function theorem?

@HerrK. Honestly? I don't know how that works.

Try to rewrite the equation into the form $F(m,n)=0$ (some terms can be simplified/canceled out). According to the implicit function theorem, if $F(m,n)=0$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial n}\ne0$, then
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm dn}{\mathrm dm} = -\frac{\partial F/\partial m}{\partial F/\partial n}
\end{equation}
